# Is it possible to export a unity game to iPod touch?

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, jailbreak

I have my iPod touch jailbreaked and want to put a game I made in Unity on my iPod to test it.
I have googeled many times but I coulnd find anything about it..

Is this possible? I have windows 8 and Mac on a virtual machine if needed. And if this is possible, is there any guide?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To test on a device you need to register as an [Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action).  The iOS Developer Program is $99 a year.

After that you need to follow [Apples instructions on adding test devices and creating provisioning profiles](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/gettingstarted/).

Once all the Apple developer stuff is setup, you can finally start testing games on device.

Back in Unity, you need to set the build setting as iOS and add you apple app id "com.mycompany.appname" to the player settings > Bundle Identifier

After Unity has finished building, open up the generated Xcode project.  Plug your iPod in and press the play button in Xcode.